# Is ImageMagick thread safe with `--without-threads` option?

Tags: multithreading, image-processing, thread-safety, imagemagick

I load images by ImageMagick using multiple threads. Is it safe when configured with `--without-threads` option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a forum post on ImageMagick.org -- ["thread safe ?"](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20090):

> ImageMagick is thread safe, we perform thousands of tests before a release with and without valgrind.

This post also includes a sample unit test ImageMagick uses

Another post -- ["What do I lose by disabling threads?"](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=9775):

> ImageMagick works fine without threads. However, a number of the ImageMagick language wrappers ... assume a threaded environment and their applications will crash and burn when they call ImageMagick methods from more than one thread of execution. With threads enabled, ImageMagick applies numerous mutex locks to serialize the splay-tree, hash, list methods, generating Wand ids, etc.

From a third post ["--disable-thread confusion"](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=9971):

> ImageMagick is thread safe but some coder modules are not (e.g. JPEG). If a coder modules is not thread safe we serialize access to the module with our own mutexes. More recent versions of ImageMagick distinguish coder module thread support for reading and writing (some modules are threaded when reading an image but not for writing or vise versa).

Therefore, the consensus seems to be that ImageMagick is still largely thread-safe using `--without-threads`, with the consequence of slower execution and the potential that some wrappers, libraries, or modules may not be thread-safe (and thus will "crash and burn").

Responding directly to your question of mult-threaded reading, however, it depends on the library you're using -- e.g., if you're using the JPEG delegate library, it is not thread-safe (source below).

libjpeg.txt:

> Note: the JPEG library currently is not thread-safe.